# Express.js vs Spring who's the best

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, spring, express

what is the best framework to start developing a strong web application?
that in a future it is easy to maintain and that in a team it is easy to develop?
maybe it's better something like Scala and the Play framework?

why use one rather than another?
who in the future will have the best from the web point of view?

I'm undecided about using one of these

Comment: They are totally different. Express is barebone web server framework and has no opinionated first-part counterpart to Spring Boot. The question is offtopic on SO.

Comment: Express is better because it uses node.js which can handle high traffic simultaneously. Whereas Spring uses java which is ofcourse much faster than node.js, but its not good for simultaneous larger traffic handling. So, (node.js + express) is best suited for REST API.

Many companies have already switched from Java/Spring to node/express.

Comment: @RiturajShakti Java/Spring can handle large traffic absolutely fine, especially using Spring Webflux. There's probably many companies switching from Java to Go or Rust as well, so it's unclear what point you're trying to make.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't say what is better.

But I like Express.js, it is easy to learn, setup(There are lot of choices in Spring can make you confused easily).

I don't compare it, you can check

- [Should I be Node.js or Java Spring developer?](https://www.quora.com/Should-I-be-Node-js-or-Java-Spring-developer)
- [What are the advantages of Spring Boot over Node.js for a RESTful web service?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-of-Spring-Boot-over-Node-js-for-a-RESTful-web-service)
- etc with [Express.js vs Spring](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=Express.js%20vs%20Spring)